# How to convert a number like 132 in time in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert a number like 1134 into time like 11:34. I saw other answers but my question is different.

I am taking input from voice recognition, so if i speak one thirty five. the input will be saved as 135.

the main problem is the input can be of any length like 15(2 digit). Please help me.

Comment: What result do you expect from `15`?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I expect 1:5 or 1:05 or even 01:05. something like that. 01:05 will be better.

Comment: Don't save it as "123" in the first place. How are you to distinguish "twelve three" from "one twentythree"?

Comment: that is the problem. I am doing it in speech recognition.

Comment: Then storing it as a single integer is probably the wrong approach. It seems like you need to get the raw words from the speech recognition, not the numbers.

Comment: Programming needs uniqueness of rules. Given `15`, you should impose a rule that convert it to a unique result, not *something like that*. My suggestion is to first analyze multiple scenarios, then define a rule for each scenario. Then come back here with a clear idea to translate into code. ;)

Comment: I dont why it is not taking the input in words.

Comment: @sentence, i know what you are trying to saw but i am a beginner. That is why i came here to atleast get a rule.

Comment: Define the result you expect from these three scenarios: a) `1`, b) `15`, c) `155`.

Comment: a) 1:00 b) 1:5 c)1:55(remember, i want it in 12 hour)

Comment: oh, and also in a) if i say one o'clock, voice recognition takes it as 1 o'clock, so i can convert a single digit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the main problem is the input can be of any length like 15(2 digit).

And I suppose that it wouldn't be a problem if all 4 digits were always present, right?

So given a number `x`, just do:

```
y = '{:04d}'.format(x)
z = y[:2]+':'+y[2:]
print(z)
```

Alternatively, you can do:

```
y = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(x//100,x%100)
print(y)
```

Comment: it solved the problem with 3 digits, and i can do 4. I can simply do 2 digits by putting a ":" in between. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the number in chunks of 100 using divisions and module and then join the parts with ":" after converting to strings with leading zeros:

```
num = 132
result = ":".join( f"{num//10**i%100:02}" for i in (4,2,0) )

print(result) # '00:01:32'
```

- A format string, e.g. `f"{n:02}"` takes the value of variable `n` and makes it a string of 2 positions with leading zeros.  (i.e. 1 --> '01')
- `":".join(...)` takes a list of strings and joins them together into a single string placing ":" between each item in the list
- `( ... for i in (4,2,0) )` is a list comprehension. it generates a 3 item list with each item based on the value of i that will be 4, 2 and then 0.
- `num//10**i` is the integer division of num by 10 to the power of i.  Inside the list comprehension (i will be 4, 2 and 0) this will produce num//10000, num//100 and num//1.  Resulting in: 0, 1 and 132
- `%100` is modulo 100. It will only take the last two digit of the computed number above:  0%100 -> 0,  1%100 -> 1,  132%100 --> 32

All this combined produces the formatted time

Another way to do it (which may work with older versions of Python) is:

```
result = ":".join(str(10000+num)[-i:][:2] for i in (6,4,2))
```

*If you don't need the seconds, you can change the tuples to (2,0) in the first example or (4,2) in the second one. Or simply use: `result = f"{num//100%100:02}:{num%100:02}"`*

Comment: can you explain this. sorry i am a beginner, the code doesnt work for me.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.7. perhaps you have an older version.

Comment: yeah, its python 3.5